# How to send a JSON as a string in API request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

Hi I am working on `RoR` project with `ruby-2.5.0` and `Rails 5`. I have an invalid `JSON` but I want to send this `json` as string(value of any key).

```
Like:-
{
    "data": "my json"
}
```

`JSON` i want to pass:-

```
**** ** JSON for Image / Page 1 ** ** ** {
        "Lines": [{
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "Coles",
                        "Left": 53,
                        "Top": 59,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 63
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Supermarkets",
                        "Left": 130,
                        "Top": 58,
                        "Height": 24,
                        "Width": 153
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Austral",
                        "Left": 296,
                        "Top": 58,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 85
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "ia",
                        "Left": 389,
                        "Top": 57,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 22
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Pty",
                        "Left": 424,
                        "Top": 58,
                        "Height": 24,
                        "Width": 38
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Ltd",
                        "Left": 476,
                        "Top": 58,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 38
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 24,
                "MinTop": 57
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "lax",
                        "Left": 78,
                        "Top": 86,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 38
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Invoice",
                        "Left": 130,
                        "Top": 86,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 89
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "ABN:",
                        "Left": 232,
                        "Top": 85,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 47
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "45",
                        "Left": 296,
                        "Top": 86,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 25
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "004",
                        "Left": 335,
                        "Top": 85,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 38
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "189",
                        "Left": 388,
                        "Top": 85,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 36
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "708",
                        "Left": 437,
                        "Top": 85,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 38
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 85
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "COLLECT",
                    "Left": 304,
                    "Top": 142,
                    "Height": 36,
                    "Width": 184
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 36,
                "MinTop": 142
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "SPORTS",
                        "Left": 161,
                        "Top": 162,
                        "Height": 23,
                        "Width": 72
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "tor",
                        "Left": 238,
                        "Top": 166,
                        "Height": 12,
                        "Width": 20
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 23,
                "MinTop": 162
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "VOUCHERS",
                    "Left": 303,
                    "Top": 188,
                    "Height": 28,
                    "Width": 182
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 28,
                "MinTop": 188
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "FOR",
                        "Left": 306,
                        "Top": 226,
                        "Height": 18,
                        "Width": 38
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "SPORTS",
                        "Left": 349,
                        "Top": 226,
                        "Height": 18,
                        "Width": 78
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "GEAR",
                        "Left": 431,
                        "Top": 226,
                        "Height": 17,
                        "Width": 55
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 18,
                "MinTop": 226
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "Store:",
                        "Left": 28,
                        "Top": 285,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 72
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "340",
                        "Left": 118,
                        "Top": 285,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 37
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 20,
                "MinTop": 285
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "-",
                        "Left": 170,
                        "Top": 294,
                        "Height": 2,
                        "Width": 9
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "CS",
                        "Left": 195,
                        "Top": 285,
                        "Height": 19,
                        "Width": 24
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "VICTORIA",
                        "Left": 233,
                        "Top": 285,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 101
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "PARK",
                        "Left": 348,
                        "Top": 285,
                        "Height": 19,
                        "Width": 50
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "EAS",
                        "Left": 413,
                        "Top": 285,
                        "Height": 19,
                        "Width": 36
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 20,
                "MinTop": 285
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "Store",
                        "Left": 28,
                        "Top": 312,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 63
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Manager:",
                        "Left": 105,
                        "Top": 312,
                        "Height": 23,
                        "Width": 98
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "John",
                        "Left": 221,
                        "Top": 311,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 50
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Chant",
                        "Left": 285,
                        "Top": 312,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 61
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "I",
                        "Left": 351,
                        "Top": 312,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "er",
                        "Left": 362,
                        "Top": 316,
                        "Height": 16,
                        "Width": 23
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 23,
                "MinTop": 311
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "Phone",
                    "Left": 28,
                    "Top": 339,
                    "Height": 21,
                    "Width": 63
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 339
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "08",
                        "Left": 170,
                        "Top": 339,
                        "Height": 19,
                        "Width": 23
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "94723299",
                        "Left": 208,
                        "Top": 339,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 101
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 20,
                "MinTop": 339
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "Served",
                        "Left": 29,
                        "Top": 366,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 75
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "By:",
                        "Left": 118,
                        "Top": 366,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 33
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Assisted",
                        "Left": 170,
                        "Top": 366,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 101
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Checkout",
                        "Left": 285,
                        "Top": 366,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 100
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 366
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "12:05",
                    "Left": 479,
                    "Top": 417,
                    "Height": 21,
                    "Width": 62
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 417
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "36",
                        "Left": 478,
                        "Top": 524,
                        "Height": 19,
                        "Width": 24
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "oo",
                        "Left": 517,
                        "Top": 525,
                        "Height": 18,
                        "Width": 24
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 19,
                "MinTop": 524
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "10.40",
                    "Left": 480,
                    "Top": 577,
                    "Height": 20,
                    "Width": 61
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 20,
                "MinTop": 577
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "31.00",
                    "Left": 478,
                    "Top": 603,
                    "Height": 20,
                    "Width": 63
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 20,
                "MinTop": 603
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "121",
                    "Left": 171,
                    "Top": 392,
                    "Height": 19,
                    "Width": 35
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 19,
                "MinTop": 392
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "24/02/2018",
                    "Left": 170,
                    "Top": 417,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 127
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 417
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "Date:",
                    "Left": 29,
                    "Top": 418,
                    "Height": 21,
                    "Width": 59
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 418
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "Descri",
                        "Left": 29,
                        "Top": 471,
                        "Height": 23,
                        "Width": 72
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "pt",
                        "Left": 106,
                        "Top": 473,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 25
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "i",
                        "Left": 134,
                        "Top": 471,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "on",
                        "Left": 145,
                        "Top": 476,
                        "Height": 15,
                        "Width": 25
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 23,
                "MinTop": 471
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "Receipt:",
                        "Left": 375,
                        "Top": 391,
                        "Height": 23,
                        "Width": 97
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "9500",
                        "Left": 490,
                        "Top": 392,
                        "Height": 18,
                        "Width": 50
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 23,
                "MinTop": 391
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "Time:",
                    "Left": 375,
                    "Top": 417,
                    "Height": 21,
                    "Width": 59
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 417
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "x%HUGGIES",
                        "Left": 31,
                        "Top": 525,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 113
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "ULTRTRM",
                        "Left": 158,
                        "Top": 525,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 88
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "NWBR",
                        "Left": 260,
                        "Top": 524,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 50
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "5APACK",
                        "Left": 324,
                        "Top": 524,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 76
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 20,
                "MinTop": 524
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "3",
                        "Left": 94,
                        "Top": 552,
                        "Height": 19,
                        "Width": 11
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "@",
                        "Left": 119,
                        "Top": 552,
                        "Height": 19,
                        "Width": 12
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "$12.00",
                        "Left": 144,
                        "Top": 551,
                        "Height": 23,
                        "Width": 77
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "EACH",
                        "Left": 235,
                        "Top": 550,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 50
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 23,
                "MinTop": 550
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "%",
                        "Left": 30,
                        "Top": 578,
                        "Height": 19,
                        "Width": 11
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "SCHOLL",
                        "Left": 56,
                        "Top": 578,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 75
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "FOAM",
                        "Left": 146,
                        "Top": 578,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 49
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "PADDING",
                        "Left": 210,
                        "Top": 577,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 88
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "IPACK",
                        "Left": 313,
                        "Top": 577,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 61
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 577
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "%",
                        "Left": 30,
                        "Top": 605,
                        "Height": 19,
                        "Width": 11
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "GILLETTE",
                        "Left": 56,
                        "Top": 604,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 101
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "MACH",
                        "Left": 171,
                        "Top": 604,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 50
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "3",
                        "Left": 235,
                        "Top": 604,
                        "Height": 19,
                        "Width": 12
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "CART",
                        "Left": 261,
                        "Top": 604,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 48
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "12PACK",
                        "Left": 326,
                        "Top": 603,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 74
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 603
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "%",
                        "Left": 30,
                        "Top": 632,
                        "Height": 19,
                        "Width": 12
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "CETAPHIL",
                        "Left": 56,
                        "Top": 630,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 101
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "WASH",
                        "Left": 171,
                        "Top": 630,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 50
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "SHAM",
                        "Left": 261,
                        "Top": 630,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 50
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "230ML",
                        "Left": 325,
                        "Top": 629,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 63
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 629
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "x%GARNIER",
                        "Left": 32,
                        "Top": 658,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 112
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "FRUCTIS",
                        "Left": 159,
                        "Top": 658,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 88
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "SHAM",
                        "Left": 262,
                        "Top": 658,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 49
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "700ML",
                        "Left": 325,
                        "Top": 657,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 62
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 657
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "*XGARNIER",
                        "Left": 31,
                        "Top": 684,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 114
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "FRUCTIS",
                        "Left": 159,
                        "Top": 684,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 88
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "SHAM",
                        "Left": 262,
                        "Top": 684,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 49
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 20,
                "MinTop": 684
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "%",
                        "Left": 31,
                        "Top": 710,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 11
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "SUDOCREAM",
                        "Left": 57,
                        "Top": 710,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 114
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "GOGRAM",
                        "Left": 185,
                        "Top": 709,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 75
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 709
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "%",
                        "Left": 31,
                        "Top": 738,
                        "Height": 19,
                        "Width": 12
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "FERRERO",
                        "Left": 57,
                        "Top": 737,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 88
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "EGGS",
                        "Left": 159,
                        "Top": 737,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 50
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "IOOGRAM",
                        "Left": 225,
                        "Top": 736,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 86
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 736
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "%",
                        "Left": 32,
                        "Top": 764,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 11
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "FERRERO",
                        "Left": 57,
                        "Top": 763,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 88
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "EGGS",
                        "Left": 160,
                        "Top": 763,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 49
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "IOOGRAM",
                        "Left": 225,
                        "Top": 762,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 87
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 762
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "MARS",
                        "Left": 32,
                        "Top": 791,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 50
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "KINDER",
                        "Left": 96,
                        "Top": 790,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 76
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "LINDT",
                        "Left": 185,
                        "Top": 790,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 63
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "2",
                        "Left": 262,
                        "Top": 790,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 13
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "FOR$7",
                        "Left": 288,
                        "Top": 788,
                        "Height": 24,
                        "Width": 63
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 24,
                "MinTop": 788
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "CREAMY",
                        "Left": 122,
                        "Top": 818,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 73
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "YOGHURT",
                        "Left": 211,
                        "Top": 817,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 87
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "850ML",
                        "Left": 314,
                        "Top": 817,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 62
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 817
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "x%SANPEl-LEGRINO",
                        "Left": 32,
                        "Top": 844,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 191
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "MWATER",
                        "Left": 237,
                        "Top": 843,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 75
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "ILITRE",
                        "Left": 328,
                        "Top": 843,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 74
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 843
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "*",
                        "Left": 32,
                        "Top": 876,
                        "Height": 10,
                        "Width": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "GOLD",
                        "Left": 58,
                        "Top": 870,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 49
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "CHOICE",
                        "Left": 122,
                        "Top": 870,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 75
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "CANOLA",
                        "Left": 212,
                        "Top": 870,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 75
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "0",
                        "Left": 301,
                        "Top": 869,
                        "Height": 19,
                        "Width": 12
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "4LITRE",
                        "Left": 327,
                        "Top": 869,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 75
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 869
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "Total",
                        "Left": 32,
                        "Top": 923,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 59
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "for",
                        "Left": 110,
                        "Top": 923,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 37
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "14",
                        "Left": 162,
                        "Top": 923,
                        "Height": 22,
                        "Width": 23
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "items:",
                        "Left": 201,
                        "Top": 923,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 70
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 22,
                "MinTop": 923
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "EFT",
                    "Left": 33,
                    "Top": 976,
                    "Height": 20,
                    "Width": 36
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 20,
                "MinTop": 976
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "RRN",
                        "Left": 34,
                        "Top": 1216,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 37
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "001210950000",
                        "Left": 86,
                        "Top": 1215,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 152
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 1215
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "AUTH",
                        "Left": 35,
                        "Top": 1242,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 50
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "304336",
                        "Left": 99,
                        "Top": 1242,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 75
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 20,
                "MinTop": 1242
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "WA",
                        "Left": 443,
                        "Top": 1055,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 24
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "AU",
                        "Left": 495,
                        "Top": 1055,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 24
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 20,
                "MinTop": 1055
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "65696971",
                    "Left": 302,
                    "Top": 1082,
                    "Height": 20,
                    "Width": 101
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 20,
                "MinTop": 1082
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "BKB40C1",
                    "Left": 444,
                    "Top": 1082,
                    "Height": 20,
                    "Width": 74
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 20,
                "MinTop": 1082
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "MASTERCARD",
                    "Left": 392,
                    "Top": 1108,
                    "Height": 20,
                    "Width": 127
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 20,
                "MinTop": 1108
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "Bankwest",
                        "Left": 328,
                        "Top": 1135,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 101
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Credit",
                        "Left": 444,
                        "Top": 1135,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 74
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 1135
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "A0000000041010",
                    "Left": 342,
                    "Top": 1161,
                    "Height": 21,
                    "Width": 177
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 1161
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "AUD$",
                        "Left": 380,
                        "Top": 1187,
                        "Height": 23,
                        "Width": 50
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "122992",
                        "Left": 445,
                        "Top": 1188,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 75
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 23,
                "MinTop": 1187
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "(00)",
                        "Left": 371,
                        "Top": 1215,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 43
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "APPROVED",
                        "Left": 419,
                        "Top": 1214,
                        "Height": 21,
                        "Width": 101
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 21,
                "MinTop": 1214
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "*",
                        "Left": 215,
                        "Top": 1353,
                        "Height": 11,
                        "Width": 11
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "z;",
                        "Left": 242,
                        "Top": 1354,
                        "Height": 8,
                        "Width": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Specials",
                        "Left": 266,
                        "Top": 1347,
                        "Height": 25,
                        "Width": 102
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 25,
                "MinTop": 1347
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "X",
                        "Left": 176,
                        "Top": 1375,
                        "Height": 19,
                        "Width": 13
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "=",
                        "Left": 203,
                        "Top": 1381,
                        "Height": 8,
                        "Width": 11
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Taxable",
                        "Left": 228,
                        "Top": 1374,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 89
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "items",
                        "Left": 332,
                        "Top": 1374,
                        "Height": 20,
                        "Width": 62
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 20,
                "MinTop": 1374
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                        "WordText": "Total",
                        "Left": 37,
                        "Top": 1430,
                        "Height": 38,
                        "Width": 91
                    },
                    {
                        "WordText": "Savings",
                        "Left": 155,
                        "Top": 1430,
                        "Height": 44,
                        "Width": 136
                    }
                ],
                "MaxHeight": 44,
                "MinTop": 1430
            },
            {
                "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "$39.18",
                    "Left": 451,
                    "Top": 1426,
                    "Height": 45,
                    "Width": 117
                }],
                "MaxHeight": 45,
                "MinTop": 1426
            }
        ],
        "HasOverlay": true,
        "Message": "Total lines: 71"
    },
    "FileParseExitCode": 1,
    "ParsedText": Coles Supermarkets Austral ia Pty Ltd
lax Invoice ABN: 45 004 189 708
COLLECT
SPORTS tor
VOUCHERS
FOR SPORTS GEAR
Store: 340 -
    CS VICTORIA PARK EAS
Store Manager: John Chant I er
Phone
08 94723299
Served By: Assisted Checkout
12: 05
36 oo
10.40
31.00
121
24 / 02 / 2018
Date:
    Descri pt i on
Receipt: 9500
Time:
    x % HUGGIES ULTRTRM NWBR 5 APACK
3 @ $12 .00 EACH
    %
    SCHOLL FOAM PADDING IPACK %
    GILLETTE MACH 3 CART 12 PACK %
    CETAPHIL WASH SHAM 230 ML
x % GARNIER FRUCTIS SHAM 700 ML *
    XGARNIER FRUCTIS SHAM %
    SUDOCREAM GOGRAM %
    FERRERO EGGS IOOGRAM %
    FERRERO EGGS IOOGRAM
MARS KINDER LINDT 2 FOR$7
CREAMY YOGHURT 850 ML
x % SANPEl - LEGRINO MWATER ILITRE *
    GOLD CHOICE CANOLA 0 4 LITRE
Total
for 14 items:
    EFT
GST INCLUDED IN TOTAL
8.50
6.00
6.00
5.00
5.50
5 50
    -
    $4 .00
2, 50
1.52
9.00
$122 .92
$122 .92
$10 - 36
24 / 02 / 18 12: 04
0553
CREDIT ACCOUNT
APSN 0000 ATC 0590
PURCHASE
RRN 001210950000
AUTH 304336
WA AU
65696971
BKB40C1
MASTERCARD
Bankwest Credit
A0000000041010
AUD$ 122992
    (00) APPROVED *
    z;
Specials
X = Taxable items
Total Savings
$39 .18, "ErrorMessage": "",
"ErrorDetails": ""
},
],
"OCRExitCode": "1",
"IsErroredOnProcessing": "false",
"ErrorMessage": "null",
"ErrorDetails": "null",
"ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds": "7.042",
"SearchablePDFURL": "Searchable PDF not generated as it was not requested."
}
```

Please help me how can i pass this `json` as value of any key. i tried to pass this json as:

```
{
    "data": "my json"
}
```

But inside the postman i got an error `Expected ',' insted of 'L'`. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_json` from `json`

Add `require 'json'`

Then send data as,

```
{
    "data": yourhash.to_json
}
```